# $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{c_{k+1-i}k!}{i!}n^i$. What is known about $\{c_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$?

Tags: reference-request, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial, binomial-theorem

Recently, I figured out that for all $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{c_{k+1-i}k!}{i!}n^i$$
where:
$$c_0=1$$
$$c_n=\frac1{n!}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{c_i}{(m-i+1)!}$$
(proof down below). The first few values of $c_n$ are:
$$c_0=1$$
$$c_1=\frac12$$
$$c_2=\frac1{12}$$
$$c_3=0$$
$$c_4=-\frac1{720}$$
$$c_5=0$$
$$c_6=\frac1{30240}$$
$$c_7=0$$
$$c_8=-\frac1{1209600}$$
$$c_9=0$$
$$c_{10}=\frac1{47900160}$$
$$c_{11}=0$$
I would like to know what is known about $\{c_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$. Some specific questions would be:

- Does the pattern of $c_n=0$ for odd $n\ge 3$ continue?
- Does the pattern of non-zero $c$ alternating between positive and negative values continue?
- For non-zero $c$, do we always have a numerator that is equal to $1$?
- Is there a closed formula?

**Proof of the formula**

We have for all $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$:
\begin{align*}
n^k &=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^k\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)^k-i^k\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{k\choose j}i^j
\end{align*}
Switching the $\Sigma$'s gives:
\begin{align*}
n^k&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{k\choose j}i^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{k\choose j}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^j
\end{align*}
At this point, we define for every $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$:
$$f(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k$$
So:
$$n^k=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{k\choose j}f(n-1,j)$$
Now, we perform a change of variable. $n$ becomes $n+1$ and $k$ becomes $k+1$:
\begin{align*}
(n+1)^{k+1} &=\sum_{j=0}^{k}{k+1\choose j}f(n,j)\\
&={k+1\choose}f(n,k)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{k+1\choose j}f(n,j)\\
f(n,k) &= \frac1{k+1}\left((n+1)^{k+1}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{k+1\choose j}f(n,j)\right)
\end{align*}
The RHS is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ and $f(n,k-1)$ is the first time a term of degree $k$ appears. Let $a_k(m)$ be the coefficient of $n^k$ in $f(n,k-1+m)$. Since:
$$\deg\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{k+1\choose j}f(n,j)\right)=k$$
we have $a_k(0)=\frac1k{k\choose k}=\frac1k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. From the origial equation it now follows that for all $m\in \Bbb{N}$.
$$a_k(m)=\frac1{m+1}\left({m+k\choose k}-\sum_{j=k-1}^{m+k-2}{m+k\choose j}a_k(j-k+1)\right)$$
A change of variable in $j$ gives:
$$a_k(m)=\frac{1}{m+k}\left({m+k\choose k}-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}{m+k\choose j+k-1}a_k(j)\right)$$
Now, we have for all $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i(k+1-i)n^i$$
Finally, we'll prove using strong induction that:
$$a_k(m)=c_m\cdot\frac{(m+k-1)!}{k!}$$
The base case ($m=0$) is pretty clear, since:
$$a_k(0)=\frac1k = \frac{(k-1)!}{k!}\cdot c_0$$
Now, assume that for all $j<m$, we have:
$$a_k(j)=\frac{(j+k-1)!}{k!}\cdot c_j$$
the induction step becomes:
\begin{align*}
a_k(m)&=\frac1{m+1}\left({m+k\choose k}-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}{m+k\choose j+k-1}a_k(j)\right)\\
&=\frac1{m+k}\left({m+k\choose k}-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{(m+k)!}{(j+k-1)!(m-j+1)!}\cdot \frac{(j+k-1)!}{k!}\cdot c_j\right)\\
&= \frac1{m+k}\left(\frac{(m+k)!}{m!k!}-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{(m+k)!}{k!}\cdot\frac{c_j}{(m-j+1)!}\right)\\
&= \frac1{m+k}\frac{(m+k)!}{k!}\left(\frac1{m!}-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{c_j}{(m-j+1)!}\right)\\
&=\frac{(m+k-1)!}{k!}\cdot c_m
\end{align*}
So now we proven using induction that $a_k(m)=\frac{(m+k-1)!}{k!}c_m$. It follows that for all $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$f(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i(k+1-i)x^i=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{c_{k+1-i}k!}{i!}n^i$$
And that is exactly what we wanted to prove. Q.E.D.

Comment: I am missing something. In the initial claim $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{c_{k+1-i}k!}{i!}x^i$, the RHS depends on $x$, while LHS does not. What is $x$?

Comment: @user58697. That should be an $n$. I'll edit it. Thanks

Comment: This might be familiar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Thanks! that probably means I can express my $c_k$ in terms of the Bernoulli numbers.